# Pass parameters inside the command line in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have a situation, I need to do the same task with the same name several times during the day at work. For example, I need to create elements in different folders but with the same name: comps/todo, srv/todo, prv/todo, enm/todo, etc. I can do it with node.js, but one at a time: `npm run srv todo`, `npm run prv todo`. What I wanted was, for example, to create everything with just a small line: `npm run all todo` and thus create all at once, is this possible with node.js?

Comment: Can't you create a new script in package.json that runs all these in sequence?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, but I can't get the parameter inside the script, how do I get the parameter?

Comment: From what it sounds like you want something like `"all": "npm run srv todo && npm run prv todo"` etc

Comment: That's it, but "todo" is dynamic, so I want to pass it as a parameter, do you understand?

Comment: I see. What OS are you on? A quick test on mac shows this will work, but I'm not 100% familiar with the limitations: `"all": "for task in $(ls ./tasks); do echo \"Running $task\"; done"`.